# Opening a PDF based on URL

Tags: python, django

So, my goal here is for a user to click the link for an invoice, and it opens up a window with the PDF of that invoice displayed. Currently, I'm getting the following error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /laptops/invoices/
Reverse for 'pdfview' with keyword arguments '{'invoice': 'uploads/wordpress-pdf-invoice-plugin-sample.pdf'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['laptops\\/invoices\\/(?P<invoice>[^/]+)\\/$']
```

Bad programming practices, I know. I just wanted to get it to work before I cleaned it up a bit, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.laptop_list, name ="list"),
    path('add/',views.laptop_add,name="add"),
    path('invoices/', views.invoice_list,name="invoices"),
    path('invoices/<str:invoice>/', views.pdf_view, name ="pdfview")
]
```

views.py

```
def pdf_view(request, invoice):
    invoicename=Laptop.objects.get(invoicename=invoice)
    pdfpath = settings.MEDIA_ROOT
    with open(pdfpath+'/'+invoicename, encoding="latin-1") as pdf:
        response = HttpResponse(pdf.read(), content_type='application/pdf')
        return response
```

laptop_invoices.html

```
<h2>View invoices</h2>
{%for i in invoices%}
<ul>
   <li>
       <a href = "{%url 'laptops:pdfview' invoice=i.invoice%}"> {{i.invoice}} </a>
   </li>
</ul>
{%endfor%}
```

Comment: Your keyword argument in error is `uploads/<name of pdf>`. If we put this in the URL form that django must have tried, it will be `invoices/uploads/<name of ur pdf>`. Looks like the extra `/upload/` might be causing trouble because in ur URL patterns there nothing like /uploads/ in any of the patterns.

Comment: I don't think it is going to like that slash in the parameter.  Try passing the parameter without the slash and either moving the file, or doing the directory navigation programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. `invoicename=Laptop.objects.get(invoicename=invoice)`was returning a `QuerySet` instead of a `string` so the path for the PDF was never going to work. Thanks for helping.